# Working with bytes in OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I need to represent 8 bit integers. I know a `char` is 8 bits, but I am still not the sure how I would perform operations like addition or bitshifting. I've come up with:

```
let ( + ) x y = Char.chr ((Char.code x + Char.code y) mod 256);;
```

but this seems horribly wrong.

Is there a better way I can use chars to work with bytes or should I use something like the stdint module?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it doesn't seem *so* horribly wrong to me. `Char.code` is a function that generates no code (identity function), and `Char.chr` just checks that the input is in range. So the amount of code is about right. Since you're doing `mod 256`, you could use `Char.unsafe_chr`, to get the code size even smaller.

On the other hand, the memory model of OCaml is such that a `char` occupies the same space as an `int`. So you aren't saving much by using `char`.

If you really want 8-bit values, possibly you want to work with sequences of them. For that, you can use the `Bytes` or `Bigarray` modules. The `Bigarray` module, in particular, allows you to store bytes but treat them as ints using the usual operators. (The Bigarray store operation does the `mod 256` for you, i.e., it truncates out of range values.)